# Do I need a try...catch for requests?

Tags: node.js, request, try-catch

I would like to know if I need a **try...catch** for incoming **request**s, like in the following scenario ? And is it redundant if I use the ty..catch and if I check typeof as well ? Would only using try..catch would handle it?

```
module.exports = function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
        // Get auth header value
        try {
            var bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
        } catch (e) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
        if (typeof bearerHeader == 'undefined') {
            // Forbidden
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
        //split at the space
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
        // Get token from array
        const bearerToken = bearer[1];
        // Set the token
        req.token = bearerToken;
        next()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few points.

1. Unless you are using ancient versions of node.js never user `var` (which has a weird scope). Always use `let` or `const` (just define the variable with let outside the catch).
2. Always use `===` over `==`
3. If you are using a library such as express, you can assume `req.headers` is always set. Unlike python in Node.Js you can access non existing properties of an object so you can remove the first try catch.
4. The `typeof` check it's ok but for extra security should be `string`
5. You should then check if the split returned two elements (`if (bearer.length > 1) {...}`)

So there is no need for a try catch in this particular code. Keep in mind that you will most likely have to write asychronous code, so error management could be more complex than a simple `try-catch` (unless you are using promises and `async await` constructs).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a scenario where it goes to catch block in your code. (I assumed you use that function as middleware ). So req.headers['authorization'] will not throw an exception.

const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
if above line not in standard way then bearer[1] will be undefined, in that case, req.token will be undefined so better to send 401 response for that